# Send attached file and text by messenger using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

When I share file by email or messengers I want to add message to it. So I made this Intent:

```kotlin
val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE
            putParcelableArrayListExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, ArrayList(uris)
            )
            subject?.let {
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject)
            }
            body?.let {
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body)
            }
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            type = "text/html"
        }
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getString(title)))
```

When I send file by email everything is okay: file is attached, text and subject are added. But when I use messenger like Whatsapp and Telegram only file without message is sent. What is the reason of this behaviour and how can I fix it?

Comment: Whatsapp and Telegram do what they want. You can do nothing. Ask the developers.

Comment: Quoting the docs for `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`: "get*ArrayListExtra can have **either** a EXTRA_TEXT **or** EXTRA_STREAM field, containing the data to be sent". There is no requirement for an app to honor both, and there is no requirement for an app to support a plain String extra for `EXTRA_TEXT`.